# "Ungroup Cells" broken in 12.3 (Confirmed by WR ... it's a bug)

Tags: notebooks, cells

** Edit:  Just got off the phone with WR.  Only one other person called in about this bug (although they did call in 3 times).  Looks like it won't be fixed anytime soon unless they get more requests to fix it.  I was told it's not a top priority like system crashes and not on the radar to be fixed as of right now.  If anyone would else would like this fixed, please write them an email.  The email is: support@wolfram.com **

I just upgraded to 12.3.1 from 12.0.  I can longer ungroup cells using the menu item while in manual grouping mode.  I can't even use the shortcut standard keyboard Control+Shift+G.

Ungrouping and grouping cells are part of my workflow. I'm hoping this is just a setting, but if not, I'd like to confirm this is a bug so I can contact WR.  Can someone else confirm this issue?

12.3.1.0 Mac OS X ARM (64 bit)

Here's a video demonstrating that ungrouping does not work:
[image]

Comment: Same behavior in version 12.2.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: @Emy Thank you for confirming.  I spoke with WR today and they confirmed it's a bug.    Not enough user demand to justify the amount of work required to program a fix. If you would like it fixed, please consider sending them an email at support@wolfram.com.

Comment: @B flat To tell you the truth, I'm not one to use Manual Grouping. I just thought I'd give it a go and dropped a comment. Is Manual Grouping key to your needs?

Comment: Thank you for helping me test!  Yes I use it regularly as my stylesheet is often changing with updates.  Some day I’ll stop making changes but for now I like to use manual grouping.

Comment: Instead of manual grouping, you can can just change the grouping via the stylesheet. And, IMHO, manual grouping is a *really bad idea*.

Comment: @TheDoctor I understand what you are saying.  I have a specific reason for using manual grouping that’s a bit nuanced.  It’s optimal for my specific situation.  Otherwise yes I would agree.

Comment: @Bflat A while ago I had a long argument with another developer who insisted the he *required* manual grouping. However, after changing the`CellGroupingRules`—both the type and precedence—implemented in the StyleSheet via a change in Screen Environment, all the functionality he wanted—and more—could be achieved *without* manual grouping.

So, perhaps you could explain how it is *optimal* for your situation.

Comment: I know how to use them and will be using them at some point in this project. However, For now I’m still working out how I want things to look.  In other words I’m not decided (yet) on what I want the cell grouping rules to look like.  I want the freedom to play around and experiment on the fly with different cell groupings in each document but also document to document.  Im creating lots of new style cells and want to have freedom of quick and easy experimentation.  I can’t do this with the auto setting on.  Yes later I will decide and turn on auto grouping.  I am fully aware of its power.